# Adding Rule To Text Afte n:th <br /> Element

Tags: css

I have a pattern like this

```
<p class="strings">
This is part 1 <br />
This is part 2 <br />
This is part 3 <br />
This is part 4 <br />
This is part 5 <br />
</p>
```

now I need to add some styles to parts 4, and 5. can you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Why not create element structure around each line then you can use the nth-child selector to style accordingly

Comment: Can your markup be modified? It is not possible with the current one.

Comment: what is your expected output? Show as image & relevant code you tried sofar.. so that we can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use `unordered list` for your requirement like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g7cwg7ax/1/)**

```
<ul class="strings">
    <li>This is part 1</li>
    <li>This is part 2</li>
    <li>This is part 3</li>
    <li>This is part 4</li>
    <li>This is part 5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.strings li {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}

.strings li:nth-child(4n+4){
      color:green;
}


.strings li:nth-child(4n+5){  
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, nice to know, bro!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap them into some **tags** to apply CSS styling:

```
<p class="strings">
    This is part 1 <br />
    This is part 2 <br />
    This is part 3 <br />
    <span class="part4">This is part 4</span> <br />
    <span class="part5">This is part 5</span> <br />
</p>
```

and then you can do whatever you want with these lines:

```
.part4 {
    color: #3399cc;
}

.part5 {
    color: #b2d025;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mateusz Kwaśniak but I am getting a dynamic structre from JS app

Comment: @Suffii: I don't think you can achieve this without changing your markup. All your text is part of the same tag and there is no way to apply styles to one part of a tag but not others.